# converts each specific letter into uppercase

Tags: php

Let's say I have a string:

```
"\System\Classes\SomeClass"
```

And I want to convert this into:

```
"\system\classes\someClass"
```

How can I do this - convert each "\X" into "\x"? Which regular expression should I use, and can I do this using regular expressions? (as far as I know they search only for the first occurrence of the searched pattern).

Comment: Regular expressions are much more powerfull than you think. So you want everything lowercase except the last C in class right ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this if last word is class always

```
$str="\System\Classes\SomeClass";
$str2=strtolower($str);
$strArr=explode("\\",$str2);

$newStr=preg_replace('~class~','Class',$strArr[3]);
$complete=$strArr[1].'\\'.$strArr[2].'\\'. $newStr;
echo $complete;
```

Comment: If you're going to do it by only camelcasing the final "class", why the hell would you use regex? (hint: `strrpos` + `substr`)

Comment: Youre right, there was an answer which I liked the most but it is now deleted : $string = "\System\Classes\SomeClass";
$string = preg_replace_callback('/\\\\[A-Z]/',
    function($matches) {
        return strtolower($matches[0]);
    },             
    $string
);

echo $string;

Answer (score 1):

Try this - [**DEMO**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/FJTkWx)

```
$string = "\System\Classes\SomeClass";
$array  = explode("\\", $string);

for ( $i = 0, $len = sizeof($array); $i < $len; $i++ ) {
    $array[$i] = lcfirst($array[$i]);
}

$new_string  = implode("\\", $array);
```

Comment: Oh, I thought there's a way to do this ONLY with regular expressions, without splitting it apart. Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 1):

You want to lowercase only the letters right after the `\`, right? I suggest you split the string by `\` and then use `lcfirst($str)` on each as Ajmal Salim suggested. Then you can implode the string again. So it would be like:

```
$parts = explode('\\', '\\System\\Classes\\SomeClass');
$parts = array_map(function($item) { return lcfirst($item); }, $parts);
$end   = implode('\\', $parts);
```